# javascript array of object add rank but don't change order of the main array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I want to add a `rank` key on each element based on `totalpremium` value(**but I don't want to change the order of objects inside array**), My current code works fine but It changes the order of the main array of object which I don't want to do.

**Array of objects:**

```
 [
  {
    totalcount: 2834682,
    totalpremium: 652553820
  },
  {
    totalcount: 1380674,
    totalpremium: 430713235
  },
  {
    totalcount: 862119,
    totalpremium: 165983898
  }
]
```

**Working Function**

```
// add rank to each object
function rank_by_key(array, key_name) {

    if (key_name) {

        array.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b[key_name] - a[key_name];
        });

        var rank = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0 && array[i][key_name] < array[i - 1][key_name]) {
                rank++;
            }
            array[i].rank = rank;
        }
    }
    return array;
}


ranked_result = rank_by_key(array, 'totalpremium');
```

**Expected Output:**

```
      [
        {
          "totalcount": 2834682,
          "totalpremium": 110,
          "rank": 2
        },
        {
          "totalcount": 1380674,
          "totalpremium": 121,
          "rank":1
        },
        {
          "totalcount": 862119,
          "totalpremium": 100,
          "rank": 3
        }
      ]
```

**Current Output:**

```
      [
        {
          "totalcount": 1380674,
          "totalpremium": 121,
          "rank":1
        },
        {
          "totalcount": 2834682,
          "totalpremium": 110,
          "rank": 2
        },
        {
          "totalcount": 862119,
          "totalpremium": 100,
          "rank": 3
        }
      ]
```

Comment: Your current code is not giving the output you say it does. Make sure you have pasted the right code.

Comment: `Array of objects` - I'm seeing an array of one object.

Comment: my bad, check the edit now :)

Comment: `sort` sorts the array *in place*. If you want to sort non-destructively you'd need to copy the array first (or do the sort manually and use that to set `rank`).

Comment: thanks for the answer but this single line do the trick for me `let array_old = [...array];` @DaveNewton

Comment: @AlwaysSunny Yes, that copies the array first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the code you provided, you seem to want the rank to take equality into account, e.g. `[10,20,30,20]` would be ranked `[3,2,1,2]` instead of `[4,2,1,3]`.

The performance bottleneck will be the sorting of your keys, but there's little we can do about it.

Here's what I got, using good old functions and intermediate variables.
Some of the ES6 syntactic sugar comes at a cost, while sets seem to work like a charm. I reverted to old-fashioned methods when they seemed to offer a good readability/performance trade-off, but that's highly debatable, of course.

```
function rank_according_to (data, key_name)
{
    // collect unique key values
    let unique_keys = new Set();
    for (let i = 0 ; i != data.length ; i++) unique_keys.add(data[i][key_name]);
    
    // sort unique key values
    let sorted_keys = [...unique_keys].sort( (a,b) => b-a );
    
    // associate a rank to each value
    let rank_of_key = [];
    for (let i = 0 ; i != sorted_keys.length ; i++) rank_of_key[sorted_keys[i]] = i+1;
    
    // Option 1: Put the ranks into the original array
    //for (let i = 0 ; i != data.length ; i++) data[i].rank = rank_of_key[data[i][key_name]];

    // Option 2: put the ranks into a deep copy
    return data.map (record => ({ ...record, rank: (rank_of_key[record[key_name]]) }) );
}
```

I changed your dataset to have more readable numbers and a case of identical key values:

```
console.log (sample)

Array(4) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​0: Object { key_one: 123, key_two: 121 }
​1: Object { key_one: 135, key_two: 110 }
​2: Object { key_one: 123, key_two: 151 }
​3: Object { key_one: 100, key_two: 100 }

console.log (rank_according_to (sample, "key_one"));

0: Object { key_one: 123, key_two: 121, rank: 2 }
1: Object { key_one: 135, key_two: 110, rank: 1 }
2: Object { key_one: 123, key_two: 151, rank: 2 }
3: Object { key_one: 100, key_two: 100, rank: 3 }

console.log (rank_according_to (sample, "key_two"));

​0: Object { key_one: 123, key_two: 121, rank: 2 }
​1: Object { key_one: 135, key_two: 110, rank: 3 }
​2: Object { key_one: 123, key_two: 151, rank: 1 }
​3: Object { key_one: 100, key_two: 100, rank: 4 }
```

Now if you ask me, assuming efficiency is not an issue, you could spare yourself some of the hassle by saving the original indexes in an "original_order" property, so that you could sort the array back into place once you're done generating rankings.

At any rate, I'm not too happy with a design that relies on side effects of shallow copies. It's confusing, much harder to maintain, no more efficient than a lot of other possible solutions, and likely to waste far more time in debugging than the extra cost of designing a sturdier solution from the get-go.

Answer (score 1):

This creates a ranks array which we can then reference in creating the new property

```js
let data = [
  {
    totalcount: 2834682,
    totalpremium: 652553820
  },
  {
    totalcount: 1380674,
    totalpremium: 43071324534435
  },
  {
    totalcount: 862119,
    totalpremium: 165983898
  }
]

let ranks = data.map(e => e.totalpremium).sort((a,b) => b-a)
let ranked = data.map( e=> ({...e, rank: (ranks.indexOf(e.totalpremium)+1)}));

console.log(ranked)
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is just a [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) by field, nothing else. Following array indicies are your expected ranks.
You can do it as follows (if you need to have `rank` in your elements explicitly):

- [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) your array copy (`sort` does mutate original array, that's why you need to create copy),
- then use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (`map` also does not mutate orginal array).

Code example:

```js
const data = [{totalcount:2834682,totalpremium:652553820},
{totalcount:862119,totalpremium:165983898},{totalcount:1380674,totalpremium:430713235}];

const res = [...data].sort((a, b) => b.totalpremium - a.totalpremium)
                     .map((e, i) => ({rank: i + 1, ...e}))
                   
                
console.log("Result: ", res)
console.log("Original data: ", data)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; } /* ignore this */
```

Comment: `Array.sort` *does* modify the order of the original array (and return it too, in the confusing "chainable calls" style). Also, according to his code sample, the OP seems to want the ranking to account for keys of equal values.

Comment: @kuroineko Yes, you are right, sort indeed mutating original array. Original array should've been cloned, before `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

You can first sort the object, loop through the result, get the corresponding object and assign the index to the `rank` property:

```js
Object.entries(arr[0]).sort(([, a], [, b]) => {
  return b.totalpremium - a.totalpremium
}).forEach((e, i) => arr[0][(e[0])].rank = i + 1);
```

Result:

```js
const arr = [{
  "A": {
    "totalcount": 2834682,
    "totalpremium": 110
  },
  "B": {
    "totalcount": 1380674,
    "totalpremium": 121
  },
  "C": {
    "totalcount": 862119,
    "totalpremium": 100
  }
}]
Object.entries(arr[0]).sort(([,a],[,b])=>{return b.totalpremium-a.totalpremium}).forEach((e,i) => arr[0][(e[0])].rank = i+1);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but this single line do the trick for me `let array_old = [...array];`

Comment: https://jsbin.com/gobohenebo/edit?html,js,output I did this way. make a copy of old array and return that one. as array keeps the reference it did the trick